# What does this syntax mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

What does the comma in the declaration below mean? Does it define two variables at once?

```
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple). In this case, the tuple is of two variables, which get assigned the result from `request()`.

`request()` returns a tuple, which is then automatically unpacked into the left-hand tuple during assignment.

If you had just

```
result = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
```

that would assign the tuple directly to result. Then you would be able to access the response at `result[0]`, the first value in the tuple, and the content would be in `result[1]`.

Comment: Some more info on tuple unpacking / assignment [here](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/book013.html#toc132).

Answer (score 3):

That's called `tuple unpacking`. In python, you can unpack tuples like this:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

See that on the right we have a tuple, packing values, and they are automatically "distributed" to the objects on the left.

If a function returns a tuple, in can be unpacked as well:

```
>>> def t():
...     return (1, 2)
... 
>>> a, b = t()
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

That's what's happening in your code.